# CollectiovView changes layout after pressing back in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have following collectionView layout (in red)

[image]

If I press go to the next controller and then press back button it looks like this

[image]

How to prevent that from happen ? My code is following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tableViewHeightConstant.constant = 5*44
    collectionViewHeightConstant.constant = screenSize.width / 2 * 2 // for testing purposes

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenWidth / 2)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You're performing the calculations for the layout's size and placement in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidLoad` isn't called after the view is loaded. Have you tried running that code in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: The better place to put it is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called whenever the superview `self.view` changes bounds.

Comment: Neither viewWillAppear, nor viewDidLayoutSubviews didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here (and reproducing this scenario myself would take some time), so I'll give it a shot. I think both the `lineSpacing` and the `sectionInset` are taken into account during layout... Could you try subtracting the `minimumLineSpacing` from the `itemSize` ?

Try something like this:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: ((screenWidth - layout.minimumLineSpacing) / 2), height: screenWidth / 2)
```

**Also, obviously set the `minimumLineSpacing` before you do that calculation, otherwise you'll work with a different value.**

As mattsven pointed out in the comments, I also am of the opinion that you should do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Another point: I would advise you to not use the screen's dimensions, but the dimensions of the underlying view controller's view.
So those are the sizes you'd want to work with:

Instead of this:

> screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
>
> screenWidth = screenSize.width
>
> screenHeight = screenSize.height

I would use this:

```
viewSize = self.view.frame.size
viewWidth = viewSize.width
viewHeight = viewSize.height
```